# Deleted tab reappearing

Tags: support, bug, new-nav

When I click on *Questions*, I see the following tabs

[image]

The only thing is, I deleted "newest" a while back. If I click "default" (my custom tab) and then I press refresh, it corrects to this:

[image]

Is this a bug? It's frustrating because I click *Questions* all the time and it takes me directly to this "newest" tab that I don't want!

Comment: Downvoters, please also leave feedback?

Comment: I've upvoted. Don't know why you got downvotes, all I know is that I had to revert back to the old tabs, because the new tabs are just BAD. It had more bugs than things that actually work